# How to downgrade Mujoco version?

Tags: openai-gym, mujoco

I installed mujoco using `pip install gymnasium[mujoco]`, how can i downgrade it to `mujoco==2.3.0`? I tried to uninstall it then `pip install gymnasium[mujoco]==2.3.0` but it seems to have some error in syntax.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```bash
pip install gymnasium[mujoco]  # install all mujoco dependencies used for simulation and rendering
pip install mujoco==2.3.0  # downgrade just the mujoco simulator
```